# How do I restrict SSL to 3.0 only in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

How do I restrict SSL to 3.0 only in apache?

I want to allow connections over SSL 3.0, but not older versions of the SSL protocol.

How do I do this in Apache 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use or accommodate to your needs the following *SSL Cipher Suite* directives:

```
#   SSL Cipher Suite:
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1   
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!NULL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXP:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
```